# Missing attributes in xml when using python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

I am trying to read this [url](http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/rest/document?id=%7B96BD66CE-2207-4D35-815B-0E5648C0185F%7D&f=xml) and trying to extract the information between this tag: "identificationInfo"

However, when I use this code:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/rest/document?id={96BD66CE-2207-4D35-815B-0E5648C0185F}&f=xml"

response = requests.get(url)

xml_content = response.content

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_content)

for child in tree:

    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

but the results I get back don't contain any attributes for the tags.

```
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}fileIdentifier', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}language', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}characterSet', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}parentIdentifier', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}hierarchyLevel', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}contact', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dateStamp', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}metadataStandardName', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}metadataStandardVersion', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}referenceSystemInfo', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}identificationInfo', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}distributionInfo', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}dataQualityInfo', {})
('{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}metadataConstraints', {})`
```

I am not familiar with xml, and I can't work out why I can't see any more information. Am I missing a step? If someone could assist, it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want to get? Just a text? `The 72 Fish Habitat Areas in this dataset are declared under Section 120 - Fisheries Act-1994 and Schedule 3-Queensland Fisheries Regulations 2008, effective 30 September 2016. This is a composite of ALL Fish Habitat Area boundary...`? Or `xml` tree of `identificationInfo`?

Comment: I am really only after the text from the tags from the <identificationInfo></identificationInfo> tree, but I would be happy to be able to print out the xml tree of the identificationInfo, but at the moment I am not getting very far with either.

Comment: Actually, the only information that I need from the <identificationInfo></identificationInfo> tree is: `<date>
                                <gco:Date>2014-09-05</gco:Date>
                            </date>` and `<CI_ResponsibleParty id="resourceOwner">
                            <organisationName>
                                <gco:CharacterString>Department of National Parks, Sport and Racing</gco:CharacterString>
                            </organisationName>`.  I need to pull this information from other xmls of the same structure so I am trying to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `minidom` instead of `ElementTree`. The code to get required values is:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import requests

url = "http://qldspatial.information.qld.gov.au/catalogue/rest/document?id={96BD66CE-2207-4D35-815B-0E5648C0185F}&f=xml"

response = requests.get(url)
xml_content = response.content
doc = minidom.parseString(xml_content)
identification = doc.getElementsByTagName("identificationInfo")[0]
date = identification.getElementsByTagName('gco:Date')[0].firstChild.nodeValue # "2014-09-05"
responsible_party = identification.getElementsByTagName('CI_ResponsibleParty')[0]
department = responsible_party.getElementsByTagName('gco:CharacterString')[0].firstChild.nodeValue # "Department of National Parks, Sport and Racing"
```

Comment: Your Awsome!! That works great!! I was about to use Beautiful Soup to do this as I had success with it last night, but this solves my problem of having to introduce a third party package.